# Access 2007 Encrypted BackEnd Slow Only With New ACCDB

Tags: ms-access

I have encrypted back-end ACCDB on Win/2003 network.

Front-end on user workstations.  Link tables and make copies.  All works perfectly.

I open a fresh blank database and link to same back-end.  It is extremely slow, but only from a new front-end.  Clicking on any tables takes forever to launch.

It appears to be a problem only if other users have the front-end application open.

I have tried renaming the blank DB to match the one that works; no difference.

It appears that if you open one front-end to a back-end ACCDB then another front-end (such as a blank ACCDB with fresh links) to the same back-end experiences serious latency.

Any ideas on what might be going on here?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the links and recreating them instead of updating them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to maintain a persistent connection.

You want to open a table that is very small (maybe just one record) and keep that open.  Then everything else responds quickly.

You can also open a form that has a small table as its recordset, as long as it keep the connection open/persistent.